# sed insert before match include leading newlines

Tags: sed

There is a .conf file needed to be edited.

```
#8889 = 192.168.27.128:22

[incomingudp]
# UDP port forwarding example
```

I want to insert a line before a match, like this:

```
#8889 = 192.168.27.128:22
3306 = 192.168.159.128:3306

[incomingudp]
# UDP port forwarding example
```

But not like this:

```
#8889 = 192.168.27.128:22

3306 = 192.168.159.128:3306
[incomingudp]
# UDP port forwarding example
```

by script [NG]:

```
sed "/\[incomingudp\]/i [Q1]" vmnetnat.conf
```

Besides, i want to replace the line when the file has a line starts with `3306 =`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
awk '
    /3306 = /{ignore=1}
    (FNR==position && !ignore){print "3306 = 192.168.159.128:3306"}
    !$0{newline=FNR}
    /\[incomingudp\]/&&(FNR==newline+1){position=newline}
    NR!=FNR
' <file> <file>
```

To replace the file, you can do :

```
awk '
    /3306 = /{ignore=1}
    (FNR==position && !ignore){print "3306 = 192.168.159.128:3306"}
    !$0{newline=FNR}
    /\[incomingudp\]/&&(FNR==newline+1){position=newline}
    NR!=FNR
' <file> <file> > tmp && mv tmp <file>
```

Or you could also do :

```
awk '
    /3306 = /{exit 1}
    (FNR==position){print "3306 = 192.168.159.128:3306"}
    !$0{newline=FNR}
    /\[incomingudp\]/&&(FNR==newline+1){position=newline}
    NR!=FNR{print $0}
' <file> <file> > tmp && mv tmp <file> || rm tmp
```

Comment: Why ? Works well with awk